# Как в существующий проект на VS2015 внедрить Cuda?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cuda

Мне по диплому нужно оптимизировать алгоритм (resize) библиотеки Magick++ при помощи Cuda.

Есть Windows 7, VS 2015, установленная через бинарник Cuda 9.1.
Создал проект "Cuda 9.1 Runtime", опробовал куду - работает.
Magick++ тоже отдельно компилируется.

Вопрос в том, как в существующий проект Magick++ на VS2015 внедрить Cuda? Т.е. чтобы в файл с исходным кодом Magick++ можно было использовать функции Cuda.

**UPD**:
Пока разобрался, как создать пустой проект и настроить его вручную для запуска CUDA кода:
1) ПКМ по проекту -> Build Depencies -> Build Customization -> Cuda 9.1 -> Ok
2) Добавить именно CUDA сорсник: ПКМ по Source Files -> Add -> New Item -> CUDA C/C++ File.
3) Указать папку к заголовочным файлам CUDA
4) Указать dll-библиотеки. Я их скопировал из шаблона проекта "Cuda 9.1 Runtime": в свойствах проекта -> Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies.
5) Еще следует учитывать, что на VS15+ целевая архитектура может быть только x64 (не x86).